# How are attributes found in Python functions?

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

I've been playing around with Python's magic methods, and I've come across an interesting behavior:

```
In [1]: def foo(x):
...:     return x
...: 

In [3]: foo.a = 10

In [4]: foo.func_dict
Out[4]: {'a': 10}

In [6]: def getter(*x):
    return 5
...: 

In [7]: foo.__getattribute__ = getter

In [8]: foo.a
Out[8]: 10

In [9]: foo.func_dict
Out[9]: {'__getattribute__': <function __main__.getter>, 'a': 10}
```

Since I overrode foo's `__getattribute__`, shouldn't `foo.a` return `5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Special methods are looked for in the *class* of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup), not amongst the instance's attributes. Thus, to affect `foo.a`, you would need to modify the `__getattribute__` method of `type(foo)` which is `function`. However, the built-in type `function` does not allow you to change its `__getattribute__` method:

```
In [7]: type(foo).__getattribute__ = getter

TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'
```

I think that is true of all objects defined in C rather than Python.